# Syntax error on token "void", @ expected

Tags: java

Does anyone know what causes the following errors? This seems like a pretty standard construct to me. Thanks (errors then code)

```
public class Emailer {

    import java.io.*;
    import java.net.*;

    public void getFile(String dlFileName,String saveFileName) {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Error was :

```
Syntax error on token "void", @ expected
Syntax error on token "]", invalid (
Syntax error, insert "]" to complete ArrayAccess
Syntax error, insert ")" to complete SingleMemberAnnotation
Syntax error, insert "enum Identifier" to complete EnumHeader
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your imports need to come before your class declaration.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Emailer {

    // ...Emailer code down here
```

Comment: No problem. Everyone starts somewhere. :)

Answer (score 1):

Move your imports above your Emailer class declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Importing Java API's should be before class/interface declaration.

This order should be followed.

```
<package declaration>
<import declaration>
<class declaration>
```